# Django - Use AJAX to "stream" the results of a query set with annotations

Tags: ajax, django, django-views

So I'm loading the counts of each value that exists in a model field. Everything is working fine, but I have to **restart my server every time I make a change in the database for the changes to take effect in the front end**.

I think AJAX might be appropriate for this kind of thing but I don't know how to. Also note that in my query I have annotations which are used in the template.

I have my views as follows:

```
def counts(request):
    duplicates = Application.objects.all().filter(is_qualified="awarded").values('school_name').annotate(name_count=Count('school_name'))
    context = {
    'repeated_names' : records,
    'duplicates' : duplicates,
    'title' : 'Disbursement Details',
}

return render(request, 'calculations/list.html', context)
```

and my urls as:

```
path('list/', default_views.counts, name='count_rows'),
```

and finally my template as:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="disbursement_table">
         <thead class=" wow fadeInLeft">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>School</th>
                <th>Number of Applicants</th>

            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody class=" wow fadeInRight" wow-data-duration="2s">

            {% for application in duplicates %}

             <tr class="clickabe-row" data-target="{% url 'dup_detail' application.school_name %}">
                <td>{{ forloop.counter}}</td>
                <td>{{ application.school_name}}</td>
                <td>{{ application.name_count }}</td>
             </tr>

            {% endfor %}

         </tbody>
    </table>
```

Is there a way I can use AJAX to regularly update the `{{ application.name_count }}` value regularly each time changes occur in the db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options in my opinion:

1. Use [Channels](https://github.com/django/channels) which is a great Websockets library for Django:

   - [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/), this is native Django feature, will allow you to know when data was save into a Model.
   - Then you just need to implement the Websocket communication in javascript side, which is relatively simple.

**signals.py** example

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=CanBusAnalyzerJob, dispatch_uid='update_job_status_listeners')
def update_job_status_listeners(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    '''
    Sends job status to the browser when a Job is modified
    '''
    job_id = instance.job_id
    group_name = 'new-job-' + job_id

    message = {
        'total': instance.job_total,
        'progress': instance.progress,
        'status': instance.status
    }

    channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()

    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        group_name,
        {
            'type': 'send_job_progress',
            'text': message
        }
    )
```

**JS code**  to test websocket connection

```
<script>
  var socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/');

  socket.onopen = function() {
    console.log("Websocket connection done!");

    if (socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
      setInterval(function() {
        socket.send('Hello World');
      }, 10000);
    }
  };

  socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    var message = data['message'];
    console.log(data);
  };

  socket.onclose = function(e) {
    console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
  };
</script>
```

For me this is way to go, but if you want something just fast, then you could create a view and register it in the urls.py file that would be called every X seconds from your frontend code. This would fetch the new data from the database and return already the html code, or just the data and process it inside the JS code.

**views.py** 
This example also is able to receive POST args, like and ID if you need (the name is setted in the urls.py file). If you just need to fetch data **delete the third line**.

```
class ToggleFavouriteSignalView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj_id = kwargs['signal_id']

        try:
            model_obj = CanBusLogAnalyzer.objects.get(id=obj_id)

            new_val = False if model_obj.favourite else True

            model_obj.favourite = new_val
            model_obj.save()

            response_text = 'Success:Signal setted as favourite.' if new_val else 'Info:Signal removed as favourite.'

            return HttpResponse(response_text, status=200)
        except CanBusLogAnalyzer.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse('Error:The object no longer exists in the database.', status=503)
        except Exception:
            return HttpResponse('Error:Please check your internet connection.', status=503)
```

**JS code**

```
//For authentication purposes
function getCrsfCookie() {
    var cookieValue = null,
        name = 'csrftoken';
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

//Runs every 5 seconds
setInterval(function() {
    var csrfcookie = getCrsfCookie();

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 503) {
            alert("Error when trying to toggle favourite!")
        }
    };

    url_arr = window.location.href.split("/")
    base_url = url_arr[0] + "//" + url_arr[2]

    var params = 'signal_id=' + signal_id;
    xhttp.open('POST', base_url + destination_url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrfcookie);
    xhttp.send(params);
}, 5000);
```